# How to fix a permisions error when adding the Cinema 4D python executable to Eclipse on OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, pydev, cinema-4d

I want to use eclipse for some plugin development and I've got it up and working on my Windows 7 machine, but I can't get it to work on my Mac. I've been following the steps outlined on [this page](http://www.smart-page.net/blog/2011/05/09/advanced-python-plugin-coding-for-cinema-4d/). Unfortunately, I get an error when I go to `preferences/pydev/interpreter-python/New..` in Eclipse to tell it where the python interpreter is. I've tried to change the file permissions under `file info` in Finder, but that doesn't make any difference.

My executable is at
`/Applications/MAXON/CINEMA 4D R12/resource/modules/python/res/Python.osx.framework/Python`.

This is the error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/MAXON/CINEMA 4D R12/resource/modules/python/res/Python.osx.framework/Python": error=13, Permission denied
```

I'm using Cinema 4D R12, Eclipse 3.5.0, and PyDev 2.1.0.2011052613 on OS X. All of the programs are up-to-date.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what does running /Applications/MAXON/CINEMA 4D R12/resource/modules/python/res/Python.osx.framework/Python give in Terminal.app ?

Comment: i get a python shell that seems to work ok.

Comment: ...but eclipse still gives me the same error.

Comment: sorry I don't have Cinema4d - but what does ls -l on the Python executable give?

Comment: -rw-rw-rw-  1 root  admin  24708 May 15  2010 python

Comment: ok, i used chmod 777 on 'Python' and now it works, thought i could get away without using terminal. do you think there would be any other files that need to be chmoded? anyway thanks for the nudge.

Comment: That looks very odd - I would reinstall - normally Python is a symlink to Versions/Current/Python and the permissions are rwxr-xr-x ie only root can write but all can run

Comment: i got it working in eclipse, but over in cinema all the plugins started throwing errors, so yes, time for a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

set the chmod of the Python file to 744, then it should work fine